# Pass stored Credential variable to new script

Tags: powershell, variables, credentials, pass-through

I have successfully built a working simple program that displays a menu and allows a user to choose which script to open and it runs in the same window.

I would like to be able to store credentials so that you would only need to enter them once while using this program and it passes them through to other scripts.

Please can someone advise.

Comment: "I would like to be able to store credentials" - for how long? Just the lifetime of the current `powershell.exe` process?

Answer (score 0):

I played around and found a solution. Seems the variables are carried through the session regardless if it runs a new script.

This bit of code sorted it out.

```
if ($cred -eq $null)
        
        {
            try {
                Write-Host "`r`n"
                $cred = Get-Credential -Credential $username
                }

            catch {
                    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "`r`nSomething has gone wrong with entering credentials. Please try run the script again or if issues persist please contact the system administrator.`r`n"
                    Return-ExitRestart
                    }
```